# How to use Model values in view page with out model attributes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I want to use model values on `view page` but in shortcode way?

For Example:

`@model.name` prints name which is assigned to model by controller.
But I want to use it with out `@model.name` by another token or shortcode?

For example now we use `@model.Name` for print its value on view page but I want that value with out using `@model.Name`.

I want to use another token which can print the same value of it.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you would expect?

Comment: I do see any reference to attributes in your question. Not sure I really get what you are asking either. You want to use the value from `@Model.Name` without using `@Model.Name`? What do you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution; I can use tuple with view bag.

A view bag is a dynamic object using session, so make a tuple and then pass it to view.